# How get access from UIViewController, which is a containerView in other UIViewController?

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uicontainerview

I has two UIViewControllers. SecondViewController is a ContainerView in FirstViewController.

I know how get access from First to Second, but have no idea how to do this opposite(Second to First).
Maybe anyone knows how I can try to do this.

Thanks for all answers and ideas!

Comment: Why does the second need access to the first? What do you need to do?

Comment: FirstVC contains some elements which changes by events in SecondVC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `SecondViewController` is properly set up as a contained (i.e. child) view controller, then its `parent` property will point to `FirstViewController`.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the view controller by using the parent property.

```
   if let vc = parent as? FirstViewController {
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set `FirstViewController` as a delegate for `SecondViewController`